# Why does Cref refer to my lemmas, definitions etc as theorems?

Tags: cleveref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem} \label{thm:one} \dots \end{theorem}

    \begin{lemma} \label{lem:two} \dots \end{lemma}

    \begin{definition} \label{def:three} \dots \end{definition}

    \begin{example} \label{ex:four} \dots \end{example}

    Reference to \Cref{thm:one} and \Cref{lem:two} and \Cref{def:three} and \Cref{ex:four}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naturally I want `\Cref{lem:two}` to yield `Lemma 2`, not `Theorem 2`.

Comment: It's known that `cleveref` has to be loaded as late as possible, even after `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `cleveref` after `amsthm` but before `newtheorem` definitions:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not work for me. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos Afraid not - I haven't used this stuff in a while. I guess you could try loading `cleveref` even later, as per egreg's comment

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the answer on the manual. The \newtheorem commands must come after cleveref.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos Cheers, I've updated the answer with this information.